# aws ec2: ipip tunnel between instances via public ip addresses

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, tunnel

Can anyone kindly tell me that it's possible or not in the first place?
Suppose:

- There are two ec2 instances

  - In one aws account/vpc.
  - In different subnets/available zones each other.
  - Runnig on CentOS 7.
- There need to create an ipip tunnel between the instances via their public ip addesses for some reason.
- And, the tunnel won't work.

  - Relating network acls and security groups explicitly allow all traffic.
  - iptables/firewalld are both disabled on each ec2 instances.
  - When the tunnel is via their public addresses, it's nicely work in fact.

To tell in details, I tried as described below, in vain:

- instance #1:

  - public ip address: x.x.x.x (elastic ip address)
- instance #2:

  - public ip address: y.y.y.y (non-elastic ip address)
- adding a tunnel on instance #1:

```
$ sudo ip tunnel add tun0 mode ipip remote y.y.y.y local x.x.x.x
$ sudo ip address add 192.168.1.11 peer 192.168.2.11 dev tun0
$ sudo ip link set mtu 1480 dev tun0
$ sudo ip link tun0 up
$ ip address show
(snip)
4: tun0@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip x.x.x.x peer y.y.y.y
    inet 192.168.1.11 peer 192.168.2.11/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- adding a tunnel on instance #2:

```
$ sudo ip tunnel add tun0 mode ipip remote x.x.x.x local y.y.y.y
$ sudo ip address add 192.168.2.11 peer 192.168.1.11 dev tun0
$ sudo ip link set mtu 1480 dev tun0
$ sudo ip link tun0 up
$ ip address show
(snip)
4: tun0@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip y.y.y.y peer x.x.x.x
    inet 192.168.2.11 peer 192.168.1.11/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- testing on instance #1:

```
$ ping 192.168.2.11
PING 192.168.2.11 (192.168.2.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.2.11 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 999ms
```

- testing on instance #2:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.11
PING 192.168.1.11 (192.168.1.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.11 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 999ms
```

Any answers/suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `sudo ip tunnel add tun0 mode ipip remote x.x.x.x local y.y.y.y` Here, you should be using x.x.x.x = remote **public** but y.y.y.y = local **private**.  The Internet Gateway knows the local instance's public IP but the local instance does not know its own public IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much Michael, your comment was the all. Here I'll quote it and close this question:

> sudo ip tunnel add tun0 mode ipip remote x.x.x.x local y.y.y.y Here, you should be using x.x.x.x = remote public but y.y.y.y = local private. The Internet Gateway knows the local instance's public IP but the local instance does not know its own public IP.

Thank you again.